# Get element by key with Firebase in c#

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am coming to a problem where I have a guid style schema in my firebase database, which I want to display a text that is `DisplayText`, but for some reason my code is not working. I am using a FirebaseDatabase.Net Wrapper. How can I map it in order to read from the database properly using a guid way schema? thanks for the help.

Code:

```
    private async Task ShowQuestion()
        {
          var firebase = new 
  FirebaseClient("https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/");
          var dinos = await firebase
              .Child("Questions")
              .OrderByKey()
              .StartAt("DisplayText")
              .LimitToFirst(1)
              .OnceAsync<GameController>();

          foreach (var dino in dinos)
          {
              Console.WriteLine(dinos);
          }
```

I tried doing:

```
   string page = "https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Questions/DisplayText.json?orderBy"DisplayText"&limitToFirst=1";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            // Reading the string. 
            string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            // Getting a reference to the text component.
            questionDisplayText = GetComponent<Text>();
            questionDisplayText.text = result.ToString();
            questionDisplayText.text = result.Trim(new char[] {'"'});
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase queries take a two-step approach:

1. You order the child nodes on their key, their value, or the value of a property.
2. You then filter on values of the thing you ordered on.

Since you order by key, the filtering operations like `StartAt()` compare the key to the value you passed. And since there is no key `DisplayText`, there are no results.

If you want to read the first question, you shouldn't use a `startAt()`.

```
FirebaseClient("https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/");
var dinos = await firebase
      .Child("Questions")
      .OrderByKey()
      .LimitToFirst(1)
```

If you want to return the results ordered by the value of their `DisplayText` property, it'd be something like this:

```
FirebaseClient("https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/");
var dinos = await firebase
      .Child("Questions")
      .OrderByChild("DisplayText")
      .LimitToFirst(1)
```

---

Since you indicated that you want to use the REST API, here's an example of how to do that:

```
https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/59384124.json?orderBy="DisplayText"&startAt="How"
```

If you want to embed this string in your code, you have a few options. The main ones:

```
string page = "https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Questions/DisplayText.json?orderBy=\"DisplayText\"&startAt=\"How\"&limitToFirst=1";
```

Or

```
string page = @"https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Questions/DisplayText.json?orderBy=""DisplayText""&startAt=""How""&limitToFirst=1";
```

And don't forget: in order to be able to filter on the server, you'll need to define an index in your security rules. In my case I did so with:

```
"59384124": { ".indexOn": "DisplayText" },
```

Also see:

- The documentation for the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering)
- This blog post on [embedding quotes in C# strings](http://davidgiard.com/2018/11/02/EmbeddingQuotesWithinACString.aspx)

Comment: JSON data is inherently unordered, so there's no way to retrieve the children in order there. Aside from that: `https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Questions/bd341******/DisplayText.json?orderBy"DisplayText"&limitToFirst=1` Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#filtering-by-a-specified-child-key

Comment: hey @Frank, can you please show me an example of my second solution with http web request?

Comment: I showed the URL in [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367022/get-element-by-key-with-firebase-in-c-sharp/59367709?noredirect=1#comment104929033_59367709). If you're having trouble making that work, please show what you did with the information I provided.

Comment: please see updated question with the "I tried doing" section with screenshot.

Comment: If you use `"` to terminate your entire string, you can't use that same symbol inside that string to wrap the `DisplayText` field name. Most programming languages allow you to use either `"` or `'`, so you can use `'` inside the entire string then. Aside from that, I seem to have missed an `=` in my first comment.  So `'https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Questions/bd341******/DisplayText.json?orderBy"DisplayText"&limitToFirst=1'` or `"https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Questions/bd341******/DisplayText.json?orderBy='DisplayText'&limitToFirst=1"` in that case.

Comment: Btw: the docs are really helpful for this type of syntax problem. Please study them as more authoritative than what I comment here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204458/discussion-between-john-micheals-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Comment: what is `59384124` in your rules? Your child of your guid?

Comment: It's the path I stored the data at, since I use a single database for all tests I do when answering questions. It also happens to be the ID of the other question you opened (where I copied the data from). You can open the link if you want to try more: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/59384124.json?orderBy="DisplayText"&startAt="How"

Comment: the link gives me a `"error" : "Constraint index field must be a JSON primitive"`

Comment: So, I did `https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Questions/.json?orderBy=%22DisplayText%22&startAt=%How&limitToFirst=1` and I am getting a ` "error": "Constraint index field must be a JSON primitive"`. is there something missing in my url?

Comment: The `%How` looks different from what I have. Specifically `%H` is an unusual escape sequence, and it looks like you're not wrapping the value in a `"` (which has `%22` as its URL encoding sequence).

Comment: yeah. Well, I changed it and now I am using `string page = @"https://PROJECT_URL.firebaseio.com/Questions/DisplayText.json?orderBy=""DisplayText""&startAt=""How""&limitToFirst=1"`  however, it returns all properties instead of `Displaytext`

Comment: Firebase always returns complete nodes. You can either ignore the other data in the client, or change your data model to only contain the data you need.